# Gridview losing changes made via Javascript on postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, postback, viewstate

I have a Gridview that I bind some data to.  I have checkboxes on each row of the Gridview that I use to delete records via Javascript.  The delete works good.  The problem I have is that when I do a postback on the page, all the deleted records reappear.  I'm assuming this is some viewstate issue.

How can I get the Javascript deleted rows to stay deleted on a postback?

Comment: A good start would be posting some code

Comment: A GridView is not a client side control and JavaScript cannot alter the data store you are using to populate your GridView.  The best you can do is mark rows for deletion, even hide them if you wish.  But the actual delete has to be done server side during a postback.  There are many ways to accomplish this but without knowing more about your code any answer would be a guess.

Comment: you have to databind the grid again on postback with the fresh datasource, that does not contain the deleted items !

Comment: and ? did it help? if not post ur code !

Comment: Thanks, I'm not in the office today to post code.  I think I'm going to store the indexes I delete client side in a hidden field control.  Then when the page posts back from the server, grab these indexes from the hidden field and go through the grid and remove the rows.  I will try this and let you guys know if that does the trick.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the rows I'm deleting on the client were added on the client by means of a file upload feature.  The user imports an excel file of data into the grid.  This uploaded data gets appended to any of the data source rows coming from SQL Server.  I only allow the users to delete these uploaded rows from the client side.  If they try to delete any server side rows, that is done by SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to databind the grid again on postback with the fresh datasource, that does not contain the deleted items ! 
If the datasource contains the old items, then they will show up again.

Comment: Thanks, this put me on the right track to getting it working.  I would upvote but I dont have enough rep yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working.  Since the server doesn't know that I deleted the rows on the client, I needed to remove the rows again on the server side on post back.

How I did this was when I removed the rows on the client, I stored the indexes I removed in a hidden field.  Then once the page posted back, I grab the values from this hidden field, loop through the grid's data source and remove the rows.  After that I simply DataBind() the grid again.